Trying to get IOKit working on XCode on the Mac
I am trying to use the IOKit power management functions for keeping the screen on. However there is something wrong as I am getting linker errors. What I have done is:

In Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Framework Search Paths -> I added link for the framework path which is 'Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks'

In Build Phases under 'Link Binary with Libraries' I clicked the + and under AppleSDK there is the IOKit.framework so I've added that.

Under Copy Files there is a link to the IOKit.frameworks which lives in 'Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks'


I assume one or more of these is wrong as I keep getting a failed build.
Does my 'Framework search Path' seem correct?
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework
I think it is nearly working as it compiles fine with no linker errors unless I add this line then it errors:
IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoIdleSleep, kIOPMAssertionLevelOn, CFSTR("My app is running"), &preventSleepAssertionID);

what are the linker errors? You shouldn't need to manually add the framework path as its part of the SDK

What SDK are you using? macOS or Mac Catalyst?

I'm using MacOS 14.4 and Xcode 15.2
I'm also linking several other Vulkan libraries which are working fine. They are in the folder VulkanSDK/macOS. Not tried adding a framework though till now.

I solved it. It turned out I was missing the Core Framework. Once I'd added that it worked.
